# python выводить число по маске XXXX

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть числа

```
a=111
b=22
c=3
```

нужно, чтобы всегда при выводе выводилось 4х значное число, т.е

```
0111
0022
0003
```

Можно это реализовать как то по простому способу, без подсчета к примеру длины строки, и добавлением недостающих нулей? Может в питоне есть какая то маска для значений?

Comment: да, можно вполне. безо всякой маски.

Comment: @strawdog и как же? не томите )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n=4
print('{0:04d}'.format(n))
```

*>> 0004*

```
n=36
print('{0:04d}'.format(n))
```

*>> 0036*

Answer (score 2):

```
[f'{a:03}' for a in range(0,100,10)]
['000', '010', '020', '030', '040', '050', '060', '070', '080', '090']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = str(a).rjust(4, '0')
b = str(b).rjust(4, '0')
c = str(c).rjust(4, '0')
```

Соответственно данные будут строковыми.